# como puedo corregir el error 91 en tiempo de ejecucion?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, microsoft-office

Private Sub VerRegistro_Click()

' Encuentra el registro seleccionado y cierra el cuadro de dialogo.

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

' Almacena el conjunto de registros del formulario RegistroDeEstudiantes.

Set rst = Forms!DialogoIrARegistro.Recordset

' Localiza el registro del Estudiante seleccionado.

rst.FindFirst (" IDcodigo = ") & Lista5   'me dice que el error se encuentra en esta línea

'Fija el valor de la propiedad Bookmark para ir al registro.

Forms!RegistroDeEstudiantes.Bookmark = rst.Bookmark

'Cierra el cuadro de dialogo

DoCmd.Close acForm, "DialogoIrARegistro"

end with
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacerlo con RECORSETCLONE sobre el propio formulario en vez de crear uno
EJ:

```
Form.RecorsetClone
with Form.RecorsetClone
         .findfirst(" IDcodigo = ") & Lista5
end with
```